# EF4 SPROC Complex Type Mapping - Problem with ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, row-number, complextype

I've been working with EF4/Stored Procedures/Complex Types for a while now, but i haven't seen this issue before.

I have a stored proc which returns a bunch of fields, mapped to a collection of complex types. Was all working fine until i introduced this extra field.

It's using `ROW_NUMBER` from T-SQL (used in ranking results):

```
SELECT ... 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Field1], [Field2]) AS [SearchRank],
       ...
FROM   @ResultSet
```

In my complex type, i have this set as a **non-nullable Int32**, and i'm also using POCO's, so i have this as a regular `int` on the POCO.

But when i try and execute the query, i get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The
>   'SearchRank' property on
>   'RankedLocationSearchResult' could not
>   be set to a 'Int64' value. You must
>   set this property to a non-null value
>   of type 'Int32'.

I just don't get it. Nowhere have i said this property/field is Int64. And my property *is* a non-null value of type 'Int32'.

Now, **i am certain the problem is with ROW_NUMBER()**.

Because if i change that T-SQL to just `1 AS [SearchRank]` (hard code, for testing), it works fine.

It's almost as like EF sees `ROW_NUMBER()` as returning Int64.

Why? Do we have to cast this as a 32-bit integer or something?

Anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after reading up on the [MSDN documentation for ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), turns out the return type for this function is **bigint**.

So i had to change the complex type to **Int64**, and my POCO property to **long**.

Then it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a view with `ROW_NUMBER()` usage for unique id generation.

In my case, even if I changed the complex type to `Int64` and the POCO property to `long`, it did not work.

I had to remove the `ROW_NUMBER()` usage from my view. I finally merged the tables used in my view and created a single table. It worked that way.

Answer (score 0):

I Casted the ROW_NUMBER() return value to INT in the query itself as follows:

```
SELECT ... 
       CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Field1], [Field2]) AS INT) AS [SearchRank],
   ...
FROM   @ResultSet
```